# scrbook: Is \recalctypearea necessary when using \onehalfspacing?

Tags: line-spacing, scrbook, setspace, layout, binding

Consider this simple **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}

\onehalfspacing
\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

While adjusting the line spacing to `\onehalfspacing`, is it mandatory to set `\recalctypearea` as well, or can I ignore the latter?

Which behavior is correct (adding `\recalctypearea` or better without)?

Comment: Commenting out `\recalctypearea` produces different behavior in the header and footer, so clearly it makes a difference (without saying which is correct).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Yes, that's true - but is it the desired behavior? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the KOMA-Script documentation:

> Frequently, the type area must be recalculated in combination with a change in the line
>   spacing (leading). Since the type area should be calculated in such a way that a whole number of lines fits in the text block, a change in the leading normally requires a recalculation of the type area.

So `\recalctypearea` should be used after `\onehalfspacing`.

There is also an example in the documentation:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,BCOR=12mm,DIV=calc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}
```

Note that `\recalctypearea` is a short version of `\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}` or `\KOMAoption{DIV}{last}` or `\typearea[current]{last}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!